# Positive Semidefinite Kernel in RKHS

Tags: regularization, kernel-smoothing, splines

The following shows part of the page 170 of **The Element of Statistical Learning** that I want to make clear.

> The solution can be characterized in two equivalent ways
> $$\min_{c_j}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}c_j\phi_j(x_i))^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_j^2}{\gamma_j},$$
> or equivalently
> $$\min_{\alpha}(y - K\alpha)^\top (y - K\alpha) + \lambda \alpha^\top K\alpha. \quad (1)$$
> The solution for $\alpha$ is obtained simply as
> $$\hat \alpha = (K + \lambda I)^{-1}y.$$

Letting the expression in (1) be $Q(\alpha)$, differentiating wrt $\alpha$ leads to
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}Q(\alpha) = -2Ky + 2K^2\alpha + 2\lambda K\alpha \qquad (2)$$

The solution for (2) is obtained by letting $\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}Q(\alpha) = 0$. That is,
$$Ky = K^2\hat \alpha + \lambda K\hat \alpha = K(K + \lambda I)\hat \alpha. \qquad (3)$$

This is where I'm stuck. I guess the author's intention was that the $K$ matrix is nonsingular. Based on the definition of [positive definite kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel), $\sum_i \sum_j c_i c_j K(x_i, x_j) \ge 0$ for any $x_i$ for given $c_1,...,c_n \in \mathbb R$. Since there is no restriction on the $c_i$ that it should be **non-zero**, this definition seems to correspond to PSD matrix, not PD matrix. So, I just assumed the $K$ matrix corresponding to each $K(x_i, x_j)$ as a **PSD** matrix. If that's the case, it's not guaranteed that the matrix $K$ is nonsingular.

Then, how does the matrix $K$ become nonsingular matrix?
Any comment about this or an error regarding the above comment would be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of a PSD matrix $K$ and the matrix $\lambda I$ (provided $\lambda > 0$) must be a positive definite matrix, consequently, it is nonsingular.

To see why, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ that is not $0$, we have $x^\top K x \geq 0$ and $\|x\|^2 > 0$, hence
\begin{align*}
x^\top(K + \lambda I)x = x^\top K x + \lambda\|x\|^2 > 0,
\end{align*}
showing $K + \lambda I$ is positive definite.

Comment: The demonstration can be even simpler if we just use the definitions of PD and PSD. If we know $x^T A x \ge 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ (definition of PSD), then we know $x^T(A+I) x = x^T A x + x^T x > 0$ (definition of PD) because the sums of squares of nonzero numbers are positive.

Comment: @Sycorax I agree, in this way less linear algebra is needed. I will update my answer.

Comment: I guess your answer implies whether $K$ is nonsingular doesn't matter and the solution $\hat \alpha$ in (3) is not unique, is this correct?

Comment: The solution is unique because $K + \lambda I$ is nonsigular regardless $K$ is nonsingular.

Comment: I mean, using the nonsingularity of $K + \lambda I$, how can I obtain the unique solution $\hat \alpha$ from (3)?

Comment: @jason1 I see what you mean now.  It looks like the author assumed $K$ itself is non-singular as well (see Eq (5.58) in the same section).  As a fact, ESL is not a mathematics book so many expositions are not 100% rigorous.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just assuming that $K$ is nonsingular makes everything clear. I understand your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$K$ is positive definite because the columns of $K$ are a **basis**. On page 169:

> The **basis function** $h_i(x) = K(x,x_i)$ (as a function of the first argument) is
> known as the representer of evaluation at $x_i$ ...