# Textbook Recommendation other than ESL

Tags: references, svm, lasso, kernel-smoothing

My current background is as follows: (core subjects only)

> Math : Linear Algebra, Analysis, (half of) Measure Theory
> Stats : Mathematical Statistics, Regression Analysis,  Multivariate Analysis

"half of Measure Theory" means I've covered upto the ch.4 (Intro. to Hilbert Space) of Stein's Real Analysis.

My advisor recommended me to study some chapters of a book **The Elements of Statistical Learning**, including the following chapters:

> ch3. Linear Methods for Regression 
> ch4. Linear Methods for Classification 
> ch5. Basis Expansions and Regularization 
> ch6. Kernel Smoothing Method 
> ch12. Support Vector Machines and Flexible Discriminants.

His main interest is focused on those chapters, so I've tried to self-study them.

But, after reading the textbook, I found the book difficult to self-study. That is, there seem to be **a number of omission** so that I can't fully understand the mathematical expressions in the book such as why the expression holds or where it came from etc. So I want to get some recommendation about other textbooks covering the same (or similar) topics of the above chapters that introduce **more rigorous mathematical explanations** on those theories.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: There are many examples, and one of them would be the table 12.1 showing the minimizing funtions of certain loss functions. If I remember correctly, the book shows the minimizers only, and there was no proof about why such functions are the minimizers.

Comment: And, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632490/372718 this is my previous question regarding the same textbook. Based on my understanding, I was confused with the original definition of non-negative kernel because the book regarded the matrix $K$ as invertible without clear explanation.

Comment: If these duplicates do not address your needs, you can find many, many more recommendations with a search. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references+machine-learning

Comment: To make it clear, my purpose of the question in the link was not asking $K + \lambda I$ is invertible (which was straightforward), but whether $K$ itself is invertible or not. // Anyhow, I want to study some other books which shares similar topics to the above chapters but shows more clear explanation w.r.t theoretical (or mathematical) ones. So I just asked for advice about it. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: The GAM book by Simon Wood has a nice intro into theory of linear models: https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood